# Не удается установить VisualStudio. Выдаёт ошибку Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Был установлен visual studio и прекрасно работал (писала на C++). Буквально месяц назад удалила за ненадобностью, но сейчас он мне снова понадобился для написания кода на C#. При установке выдаёт такое окошко. PackageId:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi; Сам Visual Studio он установил, но не устанавливает пакеты.

Попробовала я уже кучу всего. Я попробовала:

- найти неполадки через командную строку через sfс (Выдал, что проблем не обнаружено);
- перейдите к C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=XXXXXXXXX папке, откройте ее и попробуйте дважды щелкнуть, чтобы запустить msi-файл вручную. Если это не сработает, пожалуйста, создайте резервную копию этой папки и удалите ее, а затем повторите попытку / восстановите установку.
- антивирус работает только от виндовс и даже его уже выключила
- установщик от windows на месте и запущен, другие программы устанавливает
- Ещё один способ не работает (В окне поиска Windows найдите редактор реестра, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши клавишу > Запуск от имени администратора > перейдите в этот каталог (если он существует): Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\90C68BBCA565FC341902D954EA3347AC > щелкните его правой кнопкой мыши > Разрешения… > Дополнительно> убедитесь, что СИСТЕМА и администраторы имеют полный контроль (доступ) к этому ключу и подразделам.) Доходит до Components и говорит, что приложение не отвечает.
- Я уже даже средство устранение неполадок windows скачала - не нашло проблем.
- Удалить всё и скачать заново
- Переустановить установщик
- Удалить файл Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=XXXXXXXXX
  Все вышеуказанные способы не помогли исправить неполадки. Прошу помочь.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1096342/visual-studio-2022-installation-error Внимание на утилиту восстановления. а также сбор логов. Ну и да, такое надо задавать напрямую разработчикам, а не на стороннем сайте.

Comment: я уже давно написала в поддержку, но хотелось бы решить вопрос побыстрее. Возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: Что сделать я написал выше, как минимум подробный лог ошибки нужен, а не лишь заголовок. С этим уже можно будет что-то решать. Пока ваш вопрос из разряда "Ребят, у меня пишет слово "ОШИБКА", как решить?", и тут я думаю понимаете, что эта "ошибка" может означать разное, например вон по ссылке выше у человека нет доступа к папке, студия не может ее создать из-за чего и выдает эту "ошибку".

Comment: О какой версии студии речь? Community? Откуда он скачан? Какая операционная система? Какая у неё разрядность?

Comment: версия студи community 2022 года, скачен с официального сайта.

Comment: В панели управления в "Удаление программ" всё выкидывала, что касается VS?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился тем, что windows был не обновлён. В итоге я не смогла его обновить из-за того, что версия пиратская, поэтому просто скачала более раннюю версию программы)

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой, помогло вот что:

Надо всё же открыть ветку в реестре HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components
В ней много элементов, поэтому открываться может очень долго, надо просто дождаться когда редактор реестра откроет её. После этого надо удалить или переименовать ключ 90C68BBCA565FC341902D954EA3347AC, после этого установщик отработал как надо.